# Created a font set with inkscape, need help reducing the space between fonts

Tags: fonts, inkscape, svg

I created a font set with inkscape, it all worked well, I converted from .svg to .tff, however I tried using the font to type and I noticed that the fonts have huge spaces between them need help reducing the space between fonts. I would need some help or suggestions on what I could do to reduce the space between the fonts.

Comment: What does "between the fonts" mean? Are you referring to space between *letters* or space between *lines* (line feeds)?

Comment: As Scott asked but more bluntly, what are you talking about?

Did you realise, a trained and experienced designer might take a fortnight to complete a font design?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) problem for proportional fonts (different than monospaced fonts). It's not that simple to fix it for the differences between blank spaces of characters. There are some professional font creators like [Fontographer](https://old.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontographer/) or [Fontlab](https://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-vi/) with automatic kerning, but is better to check it manually. I'm not sure Inkscape has a font kerning manager feature.

Comment: Inkscape has kerning but I am not sure how to adjust the space with this, in kerning set up, I can see two drop down menus, one labelled 1st glyph and the second labelled 2nd glyph, then there's first unicode range and second unicode range. I am new to using inkscape, so I am not really sure what I am looking at here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a gif:
https://framadrive.org/s/kPWdsMZ273qJD2c

You select the two letters between which you want to change the kerning (glyph a = first letter, glyph b = second letter), click on 'add pair', then they'll be added to the list.

Then you select the item in the list, and move the slider.

To make letters appear in the optimal position from the start, position their left borders at a useful distance from each other before you click on 'get curves from selection', i.e. put them directly on top of each other, and align their left edges, and then adjust where they are meant to overlap (if you're making a font that is written left to right, that is).

Comment: I followed the gif tutorial, but I am having some problems, when I click add pair, a white pop up box opens up and it stays that way, I am unable to click anything and when I close the pop up box, inkscape program closes also

Comment: stan, what's your OS and Inkscape version? Any command line output if you start Inkscape via command line (use inkscape.com on Windows)? Could be : https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1688746 or https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1170002 .